# FFmpeg concat audio with video or gif looping

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I'm looking for a solution in FFmpeg to merge audio (mp3) with a short video loop, or gif.

I've already been able to generate a video from an image by joining with audio, but the video stays static frame for the audio duration, the command to make this:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i imagem.jpg -i audio.mp3 -vcodec h264 -tune stillimage -acodec aac -b:a 64k -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest video.mp4
```

I need video that has the duration of the audio, but that uses a loop of another mp4 or a gif. To keep repeating for the duration of the audio.

Answer (score 0):

To do this with a **video** (MP4 or other format) you should use the Concatenate demuxer.

First create a text file with a list of the paths of the videos you want to concatenate. In your case it will be a list of the same video file, like the following.

```
# mylist.txt
file /your/path/video.mp4
file /your/path/video.mp4
file /your/path/video.mp4
```

The paths can be absolute or relative.
Then you need to use the `concat` demuxer option.

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i mylist.txt -c copy output.mp4
```

This will generate an mp4 with your original video looping 3 times. If your original video is 4 seconds long, then the output will be 12 seconds long. I suggest that you create a video just a bit longer than your audio track and then use the `-shortest` option when creating your final video.

You can add the audio within this same command like you do in your post. So, all together will look like this:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i mylist.txt -i audio.mp3 -c:v copy -c:a copy -shortest output.mp4
```

In my example I do a stream copy for my output (this will work just fine and will be very fast), but you can use the codecs you want for yours (like H264 and AAC like your post).

You can find more info in the [concat demuxer documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat) or better yet the [concat wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate).

At the moment I don't know if there's a way to do this with a **gif** file.